# Gulp — не удается выполнить задачи последовательно. В чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: node.js, gulp, сборка

Цель:

1. Сделать сборку в папку build
2. Скопировать из build некоторые файлы в заданную папку.

Когда запускаю эти задачи по очереди вручную - все работает

```
gulp build
gulp copy
```

Когда пытаюсь запустить последовательно - копирование не выполняется.

```
const runSequence  = require("run-sequence");
gulp.task('default', function(cb) {
    return runSequence(
        'build',
        'copy'
        cb
    );
});
```

В чем может быть причина? Что может помочь?

Comment: Сделать одну задачу зависимой от другой, не вариант? (без привлечения run-sequence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Андрею Санычу aka mountpoint.

Проблема была в пропущенном return в одной из задач. 
Т.е.

```
gulp.task('name', function(cb) {
    return ...
});
```

Именно он сингализирует об окончании задачи и позволяет выполнять задачи синхронно.